# Showing comma separated dropdown values from column in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved multiple choices from dropdown select menu into database field and separate them with comma. How can I load now them in dropdown menu again?
They are saved as: `choice1`,`choice2`,`choice55`...etc. Currently my query joining two tables and it's look's like this:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql="SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM form_fields t1, user_choices t2
    WHERE t1.field_name = t2.field_name
    and group_id=1 and user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." 

    echo '<select class="form-control" name="program">';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_program){
            echo '<option value='.$row_program['field_name'].'>'.$row_program['field_name'].'</option>'; 
    }
echo '</select>';
```

So I need to display values from `user_choices t2` column `program`. This query showing result if there is only one value in the column. But when there is multiple value saved with comma showing error

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...
```

Comment: try to use `explode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode()` with comma so its give you array of options and then set dynamic option values in dropdown.

```
<?php
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql="SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM form_fields t1, user_choices t2
    WHERE t1.field_name = t2.field_name
    and group_id=1 and user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." ";

echo '<select class="form-control" name="program">';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_program){
        $options = $row_program['field_name'];
        $optionsArr = explode(",", $options);   
        foreach ($optionsArr as $row){
            echo '<option value='.$row.'>'.$row.'</option>'; 
        }
    }
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank's but how to make this `$options = "choice1,choice2,choice3";`? I don't know what options are...

Comment: Got this error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array`... on this line `$options = $result['field_name']; `

Comment: print_r($result) and give that array please. as i dont know what you get in pdo query. I have just give you similar example.

Comment: print_r($result) return-> `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM form_fields t1, user_choices t2 WHERE t1.field_name = t2.field_name and group_id=1 and user_id=67 )`

Comment: @RuchishParikh, missing `$result = $pdo->query($sql);`

Comment: print_r($optionsArr) give that array value please.

Comment: I don't see anything,.. and by anything I mean really anything.

Comment: then array is empty so surely your query not returning you result. please run your query in mysql directly and check what you get.

Comment: Hm, when I query in database it is showing zero row.. that's not possible.

Comment: yes this code is correct just you need to change your query and check with this code. its work correctly as u need. Thanks.. Once you get correct result please set UV and correct the answer so its useful for other viewers. @BStud

Comment: I changed the query and now I only query by one table user_choices but now I take only first letter from each value.. how to take whole name? –

Comment: remove $key and try.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this, as you need, `program` column values :

```
<?php
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql="SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM form_fields t1, user_choices t2
    WHERE t1.field_name = t2.field_name
    and group_id=1 and user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." ";
//$result = $pdo->query($sql);

echo '<select class="form-control" name="program">';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_program){
    $options = $row_program['program'];// as you need this column values
    $optionsArr = explode(",", $options);   
    foreach ($optionsArr as $key=>$row){
        echo '<option value='.$row[$key].'>'.$row[$key].'</option>'; 
    }
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Hm.. still empty and I'm sure there is values in the column for this user_id

Comment: @BStud, echo your query and run it in db, check whether you get any response or not

Comment: Hm, when I query in database it is showing zero row.. that's not possible.

Comment: I changed the query and now I only query by one table `user_choices` but now I take only first letter from each value.. how to take whole name?